What is this Apache Derby syntax error, and how can I fix it?
I'm following this excellent Spring Boot Quick Start tutorial. I was doing well until I got to session #29, where I'm connecting my service to the embedded Apache Derby DB, and implementing the GET and PUT commands. I pretty much followed the author's code, and have the following.
package io.javabrains.springbootstarter.topc;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String desc;

    public Topic(){}
    
    public Topic(String id, String name, String desc) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
}

------------------------------------

package io.javabrains.springbootstarter.topc;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TopicService {
    
    @Autowired
    TopicRepository topicRepository;

    private List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Topic("spring", "Spring Framework", "SF desc"),
                new Topic("java", "Core Java", "CJ desc"),
                new Topic("javascript", "Java Script", "JS desc")               
                ));
                
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
        // return topics;
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
        topicRepository.findAll().forEach(topics::add);
        return topics;
    }
    
    public Topic getTopic(final String id) {
        return topics.stream().filter(t -> t.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get();
    }

    public void addTopic(final Topic topic) {
        // topics.add(topic);
        topicRepository.save(topic);
    }

    public void updateTopic(Topic topic, String id) {
        for (Topic t : topics) {
            if (t.getId().equals(id)) {
                topics.set(topics.indexOf(t), topic);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteTopic(String id) {
        topics.removeIf(t -> t.getId().equals(id));
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------

package io.javabrains.springbootstarter.topc;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic, String> {

}

-----------------------------------------------

package io.javabrains.springbootstarter.topc;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicsController {
    @Autowired
    private TopicService topicService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    public List<Topic> getAllTopics() {
        return topicService.getAllTopics();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    public Topic getTopic(@PathVariable String id) {
        return topicService.getTopic(id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/topics")
    public void addTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic) {
        topicService.addTopic(topic);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.PUT, value="/topics/{id}")
    public void updateTopic(@RequestBody Topic topic, @PathVariable String id) {
        topicService.updateTopic(topic, id);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/topics/{id}")
    public void deleteTopic(@PathVariable String id) {
        topicService.deleteTopic(id);
    }
}

When I start the service, I get

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.5)

2024-05-18T14:33:23.772-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] i.j.s.CourseApiDataApplication           : Starting CourseApiDataApplication using Java 17.0.11 with PID 70332 (/Users/cfouts/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE/course-api-data/target/classes started by cfouts in /Users/cfouts/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.22.1.RELEASE/course-api-data)
2024-05-18T14:33:23.776-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] i.j.s.CourseApiDataApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-18T14:33:24.306-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-18T14:33:24.348-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interface.
2024-05-18T14:33:24.762-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-18T14:33:24.778-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-18T14:33:24.778-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.20]
2024-05-18T14:33:24.834-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-18T14:33:24.835-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1012 ms
2024-05-18T14:33:25.078-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-05-18T14:33:25.119-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-05-18T14:33:25.145-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-05-18T14:33:25.322-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-05-18T14:33:25.343-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-05-18T14:33:25.346-04:00  WARN 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] c.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource    : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2024-05-18T14:33:25.599-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Feature not implemented: No details.)
2024-05-18T14:33:25.600-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@465134665 (XID = 166), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = memory:289b3e21-3d50-4500-b770-e6f9a0ab7601), (DRDAID = null) 
2024-05-18T14:33:25.607-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-05-18T14:33:25.653-04:00  WARN 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection@465134665 (XID = 166), (SESSIONID = 1), (DATABASE = memory:289b3e21-3d50-4500-b770-e6f9a0ab7601), (DRDAID = null)  marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(0A000), ErrorCode(20000)

java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Feature not implemented: No details.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:106) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:141) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:225) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:220) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.notImplemented(Util.java:289) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.notImplemented(Util.java:285) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createNClob(EmbedConnection.java:3728) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.createNClob(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreationHelper.canCreateNClob(LobCreationHelper.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreationHelper.getSupportedContextualLobTypes(LobCreationHelper.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$1.execute(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:223) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiDataApplication.main(CourseApiDataApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException: Feature not implemented: No details.
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:299) ~[derbyshared-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(SQLExceptionFactory.java:170) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:75) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 52 common frames omitted

2024-05-18T14:33:26.226-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-05-18T14:33:26.457-04:00  WARN 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table topic (id varchar(255) not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC [Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 47.]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table topic (id varchar(255) not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC [Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 47.]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:574) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:514) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForSchemaExport.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366) ~[spring-orm-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
    at io.javabrains.springbootstarter.CourseApiDataApplication.main(CourseApiDataApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 47.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory.java:103) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:230) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(TransactionResourceImpl.java:431) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(TransactionResourceImpl.java:360) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(EmbedConnection.java:2400) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(ConnectionChild.java:86) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(EmbedStatement.java:697) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(EmbedStatement.java:637) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException: Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 47.
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:299) ~[derbyshared-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.shared.common.error.StandardException.newException(StandardException.java:294) ~[derbyshared-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatementOrSearchCondition(ParserImpl.java:175) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(ParserImpl.java:130) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(GenericStatement.java:359) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(GenericStatement.java:99) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(GenericLanguageConnectionContext.java:1114) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(EmbedStatement.java:689) ~[derby-10.16.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2024-05-18T14:33:26.460-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-05-18T14:33:26.636-04:00  WARN 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-05-18T14:33:26.896-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-05-18T14:33:26.904-04:00  INFO 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] i.j.s.CourseApiDataApplication           : Started CourseApiDataApplication in 3.471 seconds (process running for 3.849)

What is this error, and how do I solve it? I'm obviously new to Spring Boot.
2024-05-18T14:33:26.457-04:00  WARN 70332 --- [course-api-data] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table topic (id varchar(255) not null, desc varchar(255), name varchar(255), primary key (id))" via JDBC [Syntax error: Encountered "desc" at line 1, column 47.]


@g00se, that's it! Thanks! I'm using a later of Spring Boot than the author is using so he didn't have this issue. Put this as an answer and I'll accept it.

desc is a keyword, an alias for describe. Better to choose a different name where possible or try backtick-quoting the name if not possible. Actually, if it means 'description' that should be the name anyway.

Or, another solution: End every name in your database objects with a trailing underscore. The SQL standard explicitly promises to never define a command or keyword with a trailing underscore. So you’ll never have a naming collision.

Ugly but interesting ;)

I find the trailing underscore quite helpful as it distinguishes the column name from the matching Java member field and from the matching real-world business term when emailing, documenting, etc.

Hmm. I might come around ... ;)
